# Xamarin Error when upgrading to netstandard2.0

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I'm tring to update a xamarim project to use netstandard2.0. But this produces the following error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.

This is my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "2.0.3",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "11.0.2",
    "System.Reactive.Linq": "4.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {}
  },
  "supports": {}
}
```

Comment: You need a bigger upgrade. No one should use `project.json` now, and please migration to package reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to `.NET Standard 2.0` can be done very simply. There are multiple articles about it, from official docs to youtube videos. Here is a short summary of few simple steps on how to do it:

1. Unload your PCL project (right click -> unload), and start editing
   it (right -> click edit)
2. Delete Everything in the csproj and insert this:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<PackageReference Include="" Version=""/>-->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

3. Add back NuGets (simply open packages.config, and add the package references above, or via the NuGet package manager.
4. Delete AssemblyInfo.cs (this is now in the csproj) and packages.config (also in csproj via PackageReference)

Source: https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/063a35fe3986e62d69aee2f0ed0607bf 
Alternatively if you are using Visual Studio for Mac you can use [Mutatio](https://github.com/yuv4ik/Mutatio) a VS extension to automate the process.